# gsutil connection timed out

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

When using gsutil tool on one of our machines we experience connection timeout with www.googleapis.com on port 443.

Here is the output when running :

gsutil -D cp gs://somefile somefile

```
Retrying download from byte 0 after exception: timed out. Trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 701, in _PerformResumableDownload
    end_byte=end_byte, serialization_data=serialization_data)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 757, in _PerformDownload
    use_chunks=False)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 459, in GetRange
    additional_headers=additional_headers)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 396, in __GetChunk
    retries=self.num_retries)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 325, in MakeRequest
    http, http_request, e, retry, max_retry_wait))
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 316, in MakeRequest
    check_response_func=check_response_func)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 365, in _MakeRequestNoRetry
    redirections=redirections, connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_media.py", line 377, in NewRequest
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 563, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_media.py", line 285, in OverrideRequest
    headers)
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_media.py", line 472, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1018, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
timeout: timed out
```

gsutil version used :

```
gsutil version: 4.14
checksum: be1511asdg6322ce640001299adf562f1dea (OK)
boto version: 2.38.0
python version: 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) [GCC 4.6.3]
OS: Linux 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
config path: /home/runner/.boto
gsutil path: /home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil
compiled crcmod: False
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong ?

Thank you very much in advance.

UPDATE. When running

gsutil perfdiag -n 1 -t lat -o

```
{
  "latency": {
    "UPLOAD_0": [
      0.1607818603515625
    ],
    "DOWNLOAD_1024": [
      0.07119011878967285
    ],
    "DELETE_0": [
      0.09166908264160156
    ],
    "METADATA_1024": [
      0.04940199851989746
    ],
    "METADATA_102400": [
      0.05705404281616211
    ],
    "UPLOAD_102400": [
      0.20428109169006348
    ],
    "DOWNLOAD_1048576": [
      0.1362459659576416
    ],
    "DELETE_1048576": [
      0.09648799896240234
    ],
    "DOWNLOAD_102400": [
      0.11574792861938477
    ],
    "METADATA_0": [
      0.049291133880615234
    ],
    "DOWNLOAD_0": [
      0.07036209106445312
    ],
    "METADATA_1048576": [
      0.04330611228942871
    ],
    "DELETE_102400": [
      0.08873796463012695
    ],
    "DELETE_1024": [
      0.0901339054107666
    ],
    "UPLOAD_1048576": [
      0.2904069423675537
    ],
    "UPLOAD_1024": [
      0.13672614097595215
    ]
  },
  "error_responses_by_code": {},
  "connection_breaks": 0,
  "json_format": "perfdiag",
  "request_errors": 0,
  "bucket_uri": "gs://55_rawdata/",
  "gsutil_version": "4.14",
  "boto_version": "2.38.0",
  "sysinfo": {
    "googserv_ips": [
      "216.58.211.80"
    ],
    "meminfo": {
      "mem_free": 1000596000,
      "mem_buffers": 810640000,
      "mem_total": 66004776000,
      "mem_cached": 33031452000
    },
    "disk_counters_end": {
      "sdc1": [
        164530475,
        128605520,
        51612678716928,
        40196403069440,
        2132224384,
        2247149368
      ],
      "sdb1": [
        166121731,
        173044263,
        51952023924224,
        40875654693376,
        2885575196,
        405173516
      ],
      "sdd1": [
        160345400,
        129359941,
        50683862937088,
        40195936092672,
        1386613852,
        705553928
      ],
      "sda4": [
        162028349,
        168070767,
        51260806299648,
        40562433085440,
        3391686628,
        148489864
      ],
      "sda2": [
        169374632,
        400069887,
        4907104705536,
        16390141161472,
        1009906996,
        561829072
      ],
      "sda3": [
        470,
        206,
        3309568,
        1486848,
        1348,
        388
      ],
      "sda1": [
        302,
        0,
        10948608,
        0,
        1820,
        0
      ]
    },
    "using_proxy": false,
    "dns_o-o_ip": "176.31.228.32",
    "boto_https_enabled": true,
    "google_host_dns_latency": 0.016680002212524414,
    "cpu_count": 12,
    "gsutil_config": {
      "SCOPE_READ_WRITE": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write",
      "SCOPE_READ_ONLY": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "DEFAULT_SLICED_OBJECT_DOWNLOAD_THRESHOLD": "150M",
      "MAX_COMPONENT_COUNT": 1024,
      "SCOPE_FULL_CONTROL": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
      "DEFAULT_SLICED_OBJECT_DOWNLOAD_MAX_COMPONENTS": 4,
      "DEFAULT_PARALLEL_COMPOSITE_UPLOAD_THRESHOLD": "0",
      "DEFAULT_PARALLEL_COMPOSITE_UPLOAD_COMPONENT_SIZE": "50M",
      "CHECK_HASH_ALWAYS": "always",
      "HAS_CRYPTO": true,
      "DEFAULT_SLICED_OBJECT_DOWNLOAD_COMPONENT_SIZE": "200M",
      "DEFAULT_PARALLEL_PROCESS_COUNT": 12,
      "CHECK_HASH_NEVER": "never",
      "CHECK_HASH_IF_FAST_ELSE_FAIL": "if_fast_else_fail",
      "IS_WINDOWS": false,
      "DEFAULT_PARALLEL_THREAD_COUNT": 10,
      "EIGHT_MIB": 8388608,
      "CHECK_HASH_IF_FAST_ELSE_SKIP": "if_fast_else_skip",
      "GOOG_CLOUD_CONSOLE_URI": "https://cloud.google.com/console#/project"
    },
    "gmt_timestamp": "Thu, 17 Sep 2015 09:04:12 +0000",
    "googserv_route": "storage",
    "load_avg": [
      11.93,
      15.86,
      12.24
    ],
    "netstat_end": {
      "tcp_retransmit": 353550182,
      "tcp_sent": 2944378757,
      "tcp_received": 975413756
    },
    "google_host_connect_latencies": {
      "216.58.211.80": 0.00419306755065918
    },
    "tempdir": "/tmp",
    "netstat_start": {
      "tcp_retransmit": 353550182,
      "tcp_sent": 2944373713,
      "tcp_received": 975409418
    },
    "ip_address": "176.31.228.32",
    "googserv_hostnames": [
      "par03s14-in-f16.1e100.net"
    ],
    "tcp_proc_values": {
      "wmem_default": "212992",
      "wmem_max": "212992",
      "rmem_default": "212992",
      "tcp_timestamps": "1",
      "tcp_window_scaling": "1",
      "tcp_sack": "1",
      "rmem_max": "212992"
    },
    "disk_counters_start": {
      "sdc1": [
        164530328,
        128605520,
        51612666826240,
        40196403069440,
        2132223424,
        2247149368
      ],
      "sdb1": [
        166121645,
        173044263,
        51952011656704,
        40875654693376,
        2885575068,
        405173516
      ],
      "sdd1": [
        160344840,
        129359927,
        50683802156544,
        40195931333120,
        1386608244,
        705553780
      ],
      "sda4": [
        162028349,
        168070763,
        51260806299648,
        40562432983040,
        3391686628,
        148489812
      ],
      "sda2": [
        169374632,
        400069887,
        4907104705536,
        16390141161472,
        1009906996,
        561829072
      ],
      "sda3": [
        470,
        206,
        3309568,
        1486848,
        1348,
        388
      ],
      "sda1": [
        302,
        0,
        10948608,
        0,
        1820,
        0
      ]
    }
  },
  "total_requests": 16,
  "metadata": {}
}
```

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with your network connection on that machine. Are you behind a firewall or a proxy? Can you try running `gsutil perfdiag` command ?

Comment: Hello Jeff, thanks for helping out. I cannot finalize gsutil perfdiag because it's blocked when "Running latency iteration 1". By the way we have firewall (in our case ufw) on this machine with all outgoing traffic allowed. Does gsutil need some special rules like tcp/udp and ports etc. authorized ? By the end of this message it seems like "gsutil perfdiag" keeps going but slowly, do you have any email I can drop you the perfdiag results ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use `perfdiag -n 1 -t lat`? That should go faster.

Comment: Great. I have run provided command and updated my post with the results.

Comment: The latencies in the perfdiag output look okay. One thing I did notice is that your system load seems to be enormous. Are there a lot of other things running on your machine?

Comment: Yes, in fact this machine is hadoop cluster node. Are you talking about 1GB free memory ? Are there any prerequisites for gsutil to be stable in context of free memory / maximum number of open file descriptors etc.? Thanks

Comment: The CPU load was `[11.93, 15.86, 12.24]`. This means your machine is wildly overloaded for CPU. I don't know for sure that it's the root cause, but I could definitely see it causing problems. It also looks like the network usage is very high.